# Offline Mapping Solution

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I am in a need of a solution for mobile devices, which will allow to display offline map with some 400 POIS of a given city. I have digged a bit and am stacked with the idea. I will develop my application with rhomobile, so I would have browser, ruby . 
Could you maybe give some hint which library and tools should I use? It seems openstreetmap is what I need , but I don't understand or don't know which tool can do following

1) Expprt the whole city  into offline file which then could be loaded by some javascript library from local folder and show

Comment: Suggestion: if you expect people to take time to answer your questions, then at least take one more minute of yours and use a spell checker for your question.

Comment: @Igor Brejc  I see only one typo , the word Expprt, which is obvious that it is about to Export.  If it's a big problem , just don't read it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that with mapnik I can generate map tiles and offline in mobile app use them. Openlayers will serve as map showing framework. 
Thanks for them who tried to help.